# Magento 1.7 - Change downloadable product url after successful order

Tags: events, magento, url, download, product

I'm having a lot of trouble to change a downloadable product url after a successful order.

Right now I'm listening "sales_model_service_quote_submit_after" and trough :

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$items = $order->getAllItems();
foreach ($items as $product)
{
    $links = $product->getProduct()->getDownloadableLinks();
    foreach ($links as $link)
    {
        $link->setLinkUrl('My New Url');
    }
}
```

I'm trying to set a new one.
It works but it seems to be reset to the original value later.
I may need to find an another observer event, but I've no idea which one is the right one.
I also tried the "before", and "success" ones.

Thanks for your precious help :).
See you' !

edit : sales_order_save_before works better ! But it executes more than once. :(

Comment: have you tried event `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before`?

Comment: Yes I did, as I wrote in the topic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

giftcards_observer_sales_order_place_after did the trick.